# How to get the most recent file

Tags: python, file

i am newbie in Python language and i need write a code that list directory that contains
files with random names, for example:

> JuniperAccessLog-standalone-FCL_VPN-20120319-1110.gz
>   JuniperAccessLog-standalone-FCL_VPN-20120321-1110.gz

I need get the more recent file

I try this, but without success.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime 

t = datetime.now()
archive = t.strftime("JuniperAccessLog-standalone-FCL_VPN-%Y%m%d-%H*.gz")
file = os.popen(archive)
```

Result:

```
sh: JuniperAccessLog-standalone-FCL_VPN-20120320-10*.gz: command not found
```

have a possibility the use this logic ?

Comment: What is `os.popen(archive)` supposed to do?  It doesn't make any sense.  Are you trying to open the file?  If yes, use the built-in function `open()`.

Comment: Very useful question even though it appears to be easy

Answer (score 8):

If you want the most recent file, you could take advantage of the fact that they appear to sort into date time order:

```
import os

logdir='.' # path to your log directory

logfiles = sorted([ f for f in os.listdir(logdir) if f.startswith('JuniperAccessLog-standalone-FCL_VPN')])

print "Most recent file = %s" % (logfiles[-1],)
```

Comment: No need to do a full sort; `max` suffices and runs in linear time.

Comment: Sure, `max` suffices, but no flexibility for slightly altered requirements (should they change, e.g. most recent 2 files).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MattH. Helps a lot for me

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get what you want using the `glob` module:

```
def GetLatestArchive():
    "Return the most recent JuniperAccessLog file for today's date."

    import glob
    from datetime import datetime 

    archive_format = datetime.now().strftime("JuniperAccessLog-standalone-FCL_VPN-%Y%m%d-%H*.gz")
    archives = glob.glob(archive_format)

    if len(archives) > 0:
        # The files should come sorted, return the last one in the list.
        return archives[-1]
    else:
        # No files were matched
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

[`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) will do what you are trying to do with with your popen call.

```
import os
import glob
from datetime import datetime 

t = datetime.now()
archive = t.strftime("JuniperAccessLog-standalone-FCL_VPN-%Y%m%d-%H*.gz")
files = glob.glob(archive)
for f in files:
   # do something with f
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a function to parse the date out of the filename:

   ```
   def date_from_path(path):
       m = re.match(r"JuniperAccessLog-standalone-FCL_VPN-(\d+)-(\d+).\gz",
                    path)
       return int(m.group(1)), int(m.group(2))
   ```

   This function uses the fact that your date and time values are representable as integers.
2. Use `max` to get the most recent file:

   ```
   max(os.listdir(directory), key=date_from_path)
   ```

Comment: Your regexp ignores what appears to be a time string after the date string and therefore would not necessarily return the latest file.