# python script to poll a folder continuously after a certain time interval and copy the new files to another location

Tags: python, file, copy, polling

I want to poll a folder continuously for any new files, lets say every 1 hours and whenever it finds a new file, it copies to a specific location.
I found code to [find latest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714491/python-script-to-test-for-most-recently-modified-file-inconsistent-results) and to [copy to another location](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/176391/how-to-move-files-to-another-directory-in-python). How do I merge this two to get the above desired result?
This also may be helpful [How to get the most recent file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788119/how-to-get-the-most-recent-file)

Comment: Have you looked at http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/ ? Please, specify your target OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For polling, the simplest solution is `time.sleep(n)` which sleeps for `n` seconds. Your code would look something like this, then:

```
import time.sleep as sleep
import sys

try:
    while True:
        # code to find the latest file

        # code to copy it to another location

        sleep(3600)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Quitting the program.")
except:
    print("Unexpected error: "+sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
```

(Because this loop can run forever, you should definitely wrap it in a `try`/`except` block to catch keyboard interrupts and other errors.) Cron jobs are a perfectly good option if you're only going to be on *nix platforms, of course, but this provides platform independence.

Answer (score 0):

The periodic nature of it suggests that you can use a cron job for it. You can set a cron job to run your python script every hour. It's then the script that handles copying of the file. That is if you're on a Unix machine

```
crontab -e // this will open your crontab file, then add
0 * * * * /path/to/your/script.py
```

above will run 0 minutes past every hour

Comment: I do not have a UNIX machine. I'm trying on Windows 7 using Task Scheduler but it is not happening. The python script embedded in batch script is not running. If I manually click on the bat file it runs, but through task scheduler it doesn't. Any solution?

Comment: I haven't used Windows Task Scheduler, but here is the first link coming up on Google: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7 I suppose you already know this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine that with more tasks in the same script the sleep is not an option, in that case you could something like this:

```
import time
interval = 3600
lasttime = time.time()

# This is supposed to run repeatedly inside your main loop
now = time.time()
if ((lasttime - now)>interval):
  lasttime = now
  doTask()
```